# UX for Angular two way data binding

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, user-experience

I have some modals/popups where user can input/edit some values. My angular implementation of modal is different from traditional modals with "Save" and "Cancel" buttons where clicking on save only saves the Data.

My modals do not have save and cancel buttons. They just have close button.

I was wondering if not having "Save" and "Cancel" buttons makes it more confusing.

Comment: This is more suited for [UX Stackexchange](http://ux.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Considering the scenario with the traditional "Save" and "Cancel" UI where:-

1. I opened the dialog.
2. I did some changes.

   1. I am OK with the changes => I click "Save"
   2. I am NOT OK with the changes => I Click "Cancel"

Now in your solution:-

1. I opened the dialog.
2. I did some changes.

   1. I am OK with the changes => I closed => The application "Saved" the changes
   2. I am NOT OK with the changes => I closed => What happens?

Do you see the ambiguity here.  What happens to the Dirty form? Do I have liberty to "Save" or "Discard" the changes?